# произведение чисел Фибоначчи C++

Tags: c++, рекурсия, числа-фибоначчи

нужно рекурсией посчитать произведение чисел Фибоначчи от 1 до N
в теории все норм, но на практике работает только для случая N = 4. подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    else return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

int fibproduct(int m) {
    if (m <= 1) return 1;
    else return fibproduct(fib(m-1)) * (fib(m));
}

int main(void) {
    cout << fibproduct(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: в этом и вопрос. мне нужно именно рекурсией. да, всех от 1 до N

Comment: Тогда что вы намеревались получить от `fibproduct(fib(m-1)) * (fib(m));`? По-вашему, произведение чисел от первого до четвертого - это произведение всех чисел от первого до 15-го? :)

Comment: На практичке рекурсию лучше никогда не использовать. Её всегда можно заменить на итеративный метод. Это будет лучше, и по времени, и по памяти.  Просто задачка для развития?

Comment: А в данном случае придётся начинать с конца, что не совсем првильно, т.к. придётся вычслять является ли N - числом из ряда Фибоначчи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть у меня ощущение, что вам нужно считать произведение всех чисел Фибоначчи от первого до N-го. Тогда надо просто правильно написать функцию произведение - произведение всех чисел от первого до N-го равно произведению всех от первого до N-1-го на N-е число Фибоначчи:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    else return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

int fibproduct(int N) {
    if (N <= 1) return 1;
    return fibproduct(N-1)*fib(N);
}

int main(void) {
    cout << fibproduct(4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не маловат ли будет  `int`? Ещё й знаковый.

Comment: @EOF Это чисто демонстрация, **как**. Понятно, что и long long'а для реальных значений будет маловато :) `int` отработает до 9, `unsigned long long` - до 13. Так сказать, не особо велика разница...

Answer (score 0):

```
int fibproduct(int m) {
    if (m <= 1) return 1;
    else return fibproduct(fib(m-1)) * (fib(m));
}
```

вот это монструозная функция,

смотрите что она делает:

```
fibproduct(fib(m-1))
```

при `m > 4` у вас `fib(m-1) > 4` и поэтому функция никогда не закончит своего выполнения, а наоборот будет только увеличивать и увеличивать кол-во итераций и в определённый момент у вас переполнится стек и программа упадет с ошибкой

Вам надо было сделать так:

```
else return fibproduct(m - 1) * fib(m);
```